# how to set the placeholder property of django-ckeditor

Tags: javascript, python, django, ckeditor

while using django-ckeditor for my website, i want to set the 'placeholder' property for the editor

I've tried to work directly in settings.py like this :

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(['placeholder']),
        'placeholder': 'blabla'
    },
}
```

and i tried this in my_app/forms.py:

```
        widgets = {
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'blabla'})
        }
```

but it didn't work! what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Use `editorplaceholder` key

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(['placeholder']),
        'editorplaceholder': 'blabla'
    },
}
```

Comment: is there any way you know of in which you can apply this on the form field instance? I have multiple ckeditor RichTextFields and for some of them would like to define their own placeholder, but cannot find any information on how to do this?